# Dual Instance running only

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm asking for help. I need to be able to only run 2 instances of my application, but with the code below more than 2 instances can still be started. I am not sure what I am missing.

Here is the code:

```
const char szUniqueNamedSemaphore[] = "Amazon.exe";
HANDLE hHandle = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 2, 2, szUniqueNamedSemaphore);
if (!hHandle)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unexpected error creating Execution!", "Amazon.exe", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
if (WaitForSingleObject(hHandle, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Game is already running 2 times, additional Execution is prohibited!", "Amazon.exe", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
ReleaseSemaphore(hHandle, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: Hi christian, if the answer helps you solve this issue you can [**accept**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. If not, feel free to show what's problem you still have.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are releasing the semaphore, thus incrementing its counter, *immediately* after you successfully wait on it, which decrements its counter. So, its counter is always 2 at the beginning of every new instance.  Do not release the semaphore until you are ready to exit the program after its work is done, eg:

```cpp
const char* szUniqueNamedSemaphore = "Amazon.exe";

int main() // or WinMain()...
{
    HANDLE hHandle = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 2, 2, szUniqueNamedSemaphore);
    if (!hHandle)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unexpected error creating Execution!", "Amazon.exe", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(hHandle, 0);
    if (ret != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        if (ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            MessageBox(NULL, "Game is already running 2 times, additional Execution is prohibited!", "Amazon.exe", MB_OK);
        else
            MessageBox(NULL, "Unexpected error waiting on Execution!", "Amazon.exe", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // do your normal work...

    ReleaseSemaphore(hHandle, 1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way windows semaphores work your third instance would block, WaitForSingleObject on a semaphore completes when the available count is *not* zero rather than the reverse. There is no inter-process primitive that will do what you are after.

I suggest that you combine a mutex and a shared memory section (that is a memory section that is common to all instances of your program) and keep a running instance count in that section. MSVC allowes syntax like the following:

```
#pragma section("myShared", read,write,shared)
__declspec(allocate("myShared")) ULONG g_uInstances = 0;
```

You culd use InterlockedIncrement/InterlockedDecrement instead of a mutex but would need to remember to decrement the count even in the case where you are over the limit.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` won't block if you give it a timeout, as the OP has done. It'll return after the timeout (or in this case, immediately).

Comment: "*There is no inter-process primitive that will do what you are after*" - yes, there is. A named semaphore is EXACTLY well suited for this task.